# Is there a limit or cost for Snapshot Listeners?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-console

With the recent [updates to Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/releases#firebase-console), there were *two new **usage metrics*** introduced to Cloud Firestore:

- Active connections
- Snapshot listeners

About **active connections**, I found out that there is a [**limit** of `1000000 (1M)` concurrent connections](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#realtime_updates). So I can understand why that metric would be useful, but what about the **snapshot listeners** metrics? That number looks quite scary and [Stackdriver Monitoring](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/monitor-usage#stackdriver-monitoring) does not mention any **cost *or* limit** for "The number of snapshot listeners across all active connections".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A listener does not cost anything extra than the document reads it normally incurs.  Please refer to the [documentation on billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) to better understand how that works.

Please [contact Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) with additional billing concerns.

Comment: Why is that metric displayed then?

Comment: Don't know.  Maybe it's to help you gauge active concurrent users, if that's interesting to you?